# Writing and accessin child class variable and function except those being inherited from parent class

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to implement and access a new data members and a new member function in concrete class other than the one inherited from parent class. But can not do that.

Real Question is as follows:

Create an abstract class `A` with 2 data members and 2 member functions.
Create two concrete classes of the `A` class, named as `B` and `C`.  Each concrete class should have 2 new data members and 2 new member functions. The data members and member functions in the 2 classes should not be the same. Write `main()` methods that create objects of each subclass, and send them enough messages to show the methods work.

Please help.

The code is --

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class A
{
    abstract void display();
    abstract void rules();
    int players;
    int length;
}
class B extends A
{
    B(int a,int b)
{
    players=a;
    length=b;
}
    void rules()
    {
    System.out.println("B rules");
    }
    void display()
    {
    System.out.println("In B players=" +players);
     }
 }

class C extends A
{
    C(int a,int b)
    {
    players = a;
    length = b;
    }

    void summary()//  PROBLEM IS HERE . CAN NOT ACCESS summary
    {
        System.out.println("rules");
    }
    void display()

    {
        System.out.println("In C players=" +players + " length=" +length);
    }
}

public class BatandBall
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Airtel Champions League");

        A obj = new B(10,3);
        obj.display();

        A obj1 = new C(11,8);
        obj1.display();
        obj1.summary(); //   PROBLEM IS HERE . CAN NOT ACCESS summary
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code and tell us what you mean with *"But can not do that . "*?

Comment: @Nazgul This is very easy..you should try it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access it because the variable you created is of type `A`, not `C`. I know that actually `obj1` is `C` but polymorphism makes it not `C`. As you can see, you are declaring an `A` here:

```
A obj1;
```

No matter what values you put in `obj1`, it is still of type `A`. So how do you call `summary`? You need a cast! This will change `obj1`'s type to `C`:

```
(C)obj1
```

And then you can just use this to call `summary`:

```
((C)obj1).summary();
```

That's easy isn't it?

---

And by the way, your `C` class doesn't implement `rules` as defined in `A`. You should probably implement that or your code won't compile.